# Reading specific values from file c++

Tags: c++, file, line, fopen, skip

I need some help with getting a code for c++,

The situation is that, i need to read a text file which contains something like:

```
//THIS LINE IS COMMENTED OUT
//THIS LINE TOO
Variable1 = "1"; //comment for this line
Address = "some text value here"; //comment for this line
```

So now i want to read this text file using c++ and retrieve the values as:

```
Variable1 = 1
Address = some text value here
```

So how do i get this done, please need your expert help.
I only managed to skip the commented lines of the text file using the code below, but dont now how to read the variables. I am new to c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
string line;
ifstream myfile ("text.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( myfile.good() )
  {
    getline (myfile,line);
    if(line[0]=='/')
      continue;

    cout << line << endl;
  }
  myfile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the data-type of the value of a line? What possible data-types are there? Do you have a grammar specifying the file-format (or any other specification)? How do you want to store and use the key/value-pairs in your program?

Comment: Ehm, you need to write a C parser? From scratch? That is a lot of work. By the way, your current code is no good, since it will miss variables in lines like `/*comment*/ var = 1;`

Comment: Look into the `find` and `substr` functions of `std::string`. They can be used to split a string into the name/value pair you need. Then use a `std::map` to store the values.

Answer (score 0):

Put your while loop like the code below. This will work definitely...

```
while ( myfile.good() )
{
    getline (myfile,line);
    while(line[i]!="\n" || line[i]!='\0')
    { 
        int i=0;

        // we have to check that there is continuously two '/' operator 
        if(line[i]=='/' && line[i+1] == '/')
        {
            while(line[i]!="\n" || line[i]!='\0') // this loop will jump next to comment
                i++;
            break; // this break is used to break the upper one while loop 
        }
        else    
            cout << line[i] << endl; // this line print all character that is before the comment
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? Because there are errors in there, and it will definitely not work.

Comment: ya i have used it.. and it will on my project... @BjörnPollex

Comment: @BjörnPollex - the format for the txt file will be, first to lines comments.. then next line onwards, variable followed by value and then the optional comment for that line